# Add or delete from connection depending on response

Tags: graphql, relayjs

Essentially, I have users who can have payments, and theses payments can be filtered with an arg.

Here is my schema, simplified :

```
type User {
  payments($filter: PaymentsFilter): PaymentsConnection,
}

enum PaymentsFilter {
  MissingDetails,
}

type PaymentsConnection {
  edges { ... }
  pageInfo { ... }
}

type Payment {
  id
  description
}
```

The `MissingDetails` filter returns only the `Payment` who are missing a description.
For example, if I have 2 `Payment` :

```
[
  { id: 1, description: null },
  { id: 2, description: 'A great payment' },
]
```

A query as such :

```
query {
  loggedUser {
    payments(filter: MissingDetails) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Would return only the first `Payment`, with `id: 1`.

I want to achieve an `UpdatePaymentMutation`, that would update the payment and depending on if the `description` is set or not in the response, I would `RANGE_ADD` it to the connection with the filter `MissingDetails`, or `RANGE_DELETE` it.
How can I achieve that ?

Comment: do you mean, you want to create a mutation named `updatePaymentMutation`

Comment: are you using relay.js, if you are then i will give an `relay` `mutation`, if not then i will give just a graphql mutation

Comment: @p0k8_ I'm using Relay, I'm talking about the mutation configs at the end of my post

Comment: i have no idea about frontend relay, but i can provide the graphql-relay solution, i have no idea of `RANGE_ADD` and `RANGE_DELETE` too

Comment: Oh ok, that is actually the whole point I'm trying to understand. I think I'm ok with pure graphql mutations, thank you anyways !